# angularjs - sharing value between factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Below is the code for a controller in Angular i am working on. I am referencing svcSPoint which is a factory registered to the module. What i cant figure is this. I am able to access svcSPoint is in the constructor as the ng-annotate is injecting the factory. However, i cant access the svcSPoint in the function SelectChanged()

What i am trying to accomplish is to set the value of a factory when an event fires in DOM. How can i capture a value in global so i can access it in a bunch of controllers and factories.

```
   'use strict';

class NavbarController {
    //start-non-standard
    menu = [{
        'title': 'Home',
        'state': 'main'
    }];

    isCollapsed = true;
    //end-non-standard

    constructor(Auth, svcSPoint) {
        this.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;
        this.isAdmin = Auth.isAdmin;
        this.currentuser = svcSPoint.currentuser;
        this.scopeSelect = 'NAL';
        this.scopeSelects = ['NAL', 'USL', 'CAD'];
        svcSPoint.scopeSelection = this.scopeSelect;

        this.svcSPoint = svcSPoint;

    }


    SelectChanged() {
      svcSPoint.scopeSelection = this.scopeSelect;

    }
}

angular.module('nalAngularDashApp')
    .controller('NavbarController', NavbarController);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem and starting to learn angular. My code started working when i changed it from factory to service. since service is instantiated as a class every time it retains all the global values. I am using service to share data between controllers and directive.